# Gmake does not include a library to a makefile project

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to include a library to a gmake command-line option, in a Windows 7x64 with MS Visual Studio 8.

Originally the application was build with a system call from C++ using the string

```
char* sCommandGmake = "gmake.exe -C \"L:\\app\\project\" -f \"project.MAK\"";
```

However I have made some changes in the system, which lead me to have to include a library which is present in 
`"C:\\Program|Files|(x86)\\Microsoft|Visual|Studio|8\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\Lib\"`

So I tried this

```
    char* sCommandGmake = "gmake.exe -L\"C:\\Program|Files|(x86)\\Microsoft|Visual|Studio|8\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\Lib\" -C \"L:\\app\\project\" -f \"project.MAK\"";
```

But the library is not present, so the build continues with error.

How should I have included this lib?

Comment: `gmake` is not a compiler. It doesn't do the compilation itself. The `-L` flag to `gmake` doesn't do what you think it means. You want the `-L` flag to your compiler I assume (which adds a location for libraries to be found).

Comment: I don't understand:  If you have VS8, why are using `gmake`?  The `gmake` facility *builds* programs not compiles them.  Why are you passing libraries to a build program?  Where's your *makefile*?

Comment: Still confused.  Did you want to execute `g++` or `gcc` instead of `gmake`?

Comment: The top application is a kind of installer. This application is built under VS. Inside this application there is a system call, which calls gmake.